# Laravel: Update multiple rows in one query

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can i update multiple rows use laravel eloquent?

I want something like:

```php
$guest = GuestJointDetail::where('guest_joint_id', $guest_joint_id)
    ->where('sort_no', '>', $sort_no)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at');

$guest->update(['sort_no' => DB::raw('sort_no - 1')]);
```

I have tried

```
$guest->update(['sort_no' => 10]);
```

and i worked!
So i think my problem is in **DB::raw**

Thank you so much!

Comment: @DhruvRaval: yes, that's why i don't know how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `decrement()`:

```php
$guest = GuestJointDetail::where('guest_joint_id', $guest_joint_id)
    ->where('sort_no', '>', $sort_no)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->decrement('sort_no');
```

Comment: 'decrement' clause is what i want, but like @dhruv's answer, it must be decrement('sort_no', 1). Anw, tks so much

Comment: `decrement('sort_no')` is enough, the default `$amount` is `1`.

Comment: oh yes, that's true, sorry for my mistake

Comment: yes 1 is default value. but for your understanding i pass 1. you can change 2nd value as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

use decrement();

```
guest = GuestJointDetail::where('guest_joint_id', $guest_joint_id)
    ->where('sort_no', '>', $sort_no)
    ->whereNull('deleted_at')
    ->decrement('sort_no',1);
```

use whereIn for multiple Ids:

```
guest = GuestJointDetail::whereIn('guest_joint_id', $guest_id_array)
        ->where('sort_no', '>', $sort_no)
        ->whereNull('deleted_at')
        ->decrement('sort_no',1);
```

Comment: That's what i want, tks so much!